# Ir de un Modal cerrarlo e ir a un section

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5

Tengo un problema que no se como solucionar yo tengo mymodal
cuando lo cierro con un boton quiero que me lleve a un section del html me explico cierrro mymodal con :

```
 $(".modal").hide();
 $('body').removeClass('modal-open');
 $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
```

y luego quiero que me direccione a un datanav que llamo contact

```
data-section="contact"
```

no se que funciones hacer para que al momento de cerrar el modal me deje en este section

Answer (score 0):

```
var section = "contact";
   if ( $('[data-section="' + section + '"]').length ) {
      $('html, body').animate({
         scrollTop: $('[data-section="' + section + '"]').offset().top
      }, 500);
 }
```

Esta solucion me funciono y al boton le agrege:
`data-nav-section="contact"`